# Height of the Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, css, height, monaco-editor

I want to make a very simple Monaco Editor: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qakahedajo/1/edit?html,output):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .me {
          height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="me" id="container"></div>
    <script src="https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs' }})

        require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
          var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: 'function x() {\n\tconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}',
            language: 'javascript',
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            scrollBeyondLastLine: false
          });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I see it in Chrome and scroll up and down, there is a scroller for the whole window. It seems that it is because the height of the editor is larger than the height of the window. I just don't want to see any scrollers. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Edit 1:** a screenshot in Safari 10.1.2 with `height: calc(100% - 24px)`

[image]

**Solution:**

With the help of the answers, here is the solution working for me:

1) we need to test this in an independent html file rather than in a JSBin

2) the key is to use `overflow: hidden`

3) as a result, the following code does not create any scroll bar while scrolling up and down, there are no lines hidden in the bottom when the code is long:

```html
<html>
    <style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .myME {
        height: 100%
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="myME" id="container"></div>
    <script src="https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs' }}) 
        require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
          var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: 'function x() {\n\tconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}',
            language: 'javascript',
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            automaticLayout: true,
            scrollBeyondLastLine: false
          });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it works just by setting body's margin and padding to 0, and the .me's overflow to hidden.

```css
.me {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This won't cause your lines in the bottom invisible, since monaco will handle the scrolling for you.

In fact you are getting the native scrollbar just because that has something to do with how monaco get the scrolling stuffs implemented. Setting the editor container's overflow to hidden will just work fine.

P.S Keep in mind that the editor's size won't change when you resize the window, so you have to detect the resizing and call `editor.layout()` manually.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED**

Use this one :

```css
.me {
    position:absolute; left:0; top:0;
    width:100%; height:100%; max-height:100% !important;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It works on my computer.

Comment: The problem of `overflow:hidden` is that when you write a text with many lines, a part of the text is indeed hidden in the bottom. This is especially very obvious in Safari. This is not what I want.

Comment: But where does `98vh` come from?

Comment: 98vh means 98% of page height.

Comment: i edited element with absolute element and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS as below

```
.me {
     height:50%;
     position:relative;display:block
  }
  .me-parent{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:100%;display:block;
  }
```

and update your html structure as below

```
<div class="me-parent"><div class="me" id="container"></div></div>
```

Check output here https://jsbin.com/timoyot/edit?html,output

this may help

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of the editor to fit the screen and use `overflow: hidden;` on the window, along with `overflow: auto;` on the editor

Answer (score 0):

There is a 30px space added by the `class="label"` div. it is outside the iframe which you are using but it takes the space in the document. [image]

So to solve your issue you have to adjust 30px in the editor by reducing it from the `.me` div.

```
.me {
    height:calc(100vh - 30px);
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you... Could you make a working jsbin for Safari? I tried, but it did not work for me...

Comment: Please change it to 35px since the iframe `class="stretch"` has padding-top of 35px which is affecting in safari. Changing it to 35px will solve globally.

Comment: I tried, I could still scroll down very far and see a scrollbar in Safari.

Comment: Try this https://jsbin.com/wemanalade/edit?html,output, for me it is working fine

Comment: I put the screenshot in Safari in the OP.

Comment: I just cloned a new jsBin https://jsbin.com/saxugipoqo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: If the issue remains just re-run the bin. Else share your bin here

Comment: I have always been testing your jsbins... the re-running does not solve the issue.

Comment: check with your safari version once since `calc` support is only after version `10.1` http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: My Safari version is 10.1.2

Comment: Try applyig this style `.me {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: calc(100% - 35px);
        }
      body{
        margin: 0;
      }` or  https://jsbin.com/jeyuracoso/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I am away from my mac now... did you try it in your safari?

Comment: yes, for me it works with both `calc` and the above code you check and let me know.

Comment: I just realised that we need to test the code in a html file rather than in jsbin. So I put a screenshot for `.me { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 24px); } body{ margin: 0; }`. As you can see there is still some margin (about one line) in the bottom. Is `calc(100% - 24px)` or `calc(100% - 35px)` or another number a perfect height?

Comment: If you inspect the iframe `class="stretch"` it has a padding of 35px so the number should be 35.

Comment: `class="stretch"` is only for iframe in JSBin, however, I am talking about testing it as an independent html file. I don't know how to determine the number in `calc(100% - XXpx)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.me {
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Whitespaces around the container cause that bug.